# PaperClip is not running on the local host - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I created a site for storing rails photo posts. Pictures are saved in AWS. Sites works fine - photos go to AWS and display on the site: https://pp-obrazkowo.herokuapp.com/pins
The problem is, entries are not showing up locally - http://127.0.0.1:3000/pins.
They will throw an error: missing required: bucket option
The site stopped working properly after configuring the paperclip service.
In addition, there is an error in the supervisor:
ArgumentError in Pins # index

Link to repository:
https://github.com/przemo88/obrazkowo

Code:

production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Ensures that a master key has been made available in either ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]
  # or in config/master.key. This key is used to decrypt credentials (and other encrypted files).
  # config.require_master_key = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress CSS using a preprocessor.
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options).
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain.
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment).
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "Obrazkowo_production"

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

  # Inserts middleware to perform automatic connection switching.
  # The `database_selector` hash is used to pass options to the DatabaseSelector
  # middleware. The `delay` is used to determine how long to wait after a write
  # to send a subsequent read to the primary.
  #
  # The `database_resolver` class is used by the middleware to determine which
  # database is appropriate to use based on the time delay.
  #
  # The `database_resolver_context` class is used by the middleware to set
  # timestamps for the last write to the primary. The resolver uses the context
  # class timestamps to determine how long to wait before reading from the
  # replica.
  #
  # By default Rails will store a last write timestamp in the session. The
  # DatabaseSelector middleware is designed as such you can define your own
  # strategy for connection switching and pass that into the middleware through
  # these configuration options.
  # config.active_record.database_selector = { delay: 2.seconds }
  # config.active_record.database_resolver = ActiveRecord::Middleware::DatabaseSelector::Resolver
  # config.active_record.database_resolver_context = ActiveRecord::Middleware::DatabaseSelector::Resolver::Session
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'pp-obrazkowo.herokuapp.com' }

  config.paperclip_defaults = {
      :storage => :s3,
      :s3_credentials => {
          :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
          :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
          :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
      }
  }

end
```

development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true

  # Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
  # Run rails dev:cache to toggle caching.
  if Rails.root.join('tmp', 'caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
    config.action_controller.enable_fragment_cache_logging = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}"
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options).
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Highlight code that triggered database queries in logs.
  config.active_record.verbose_query_logs = true

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Suppress logger output for asset requests.
  config.assets.quiet = true

  # Raises error for missing translations.
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  # Use an evented file watcher to asynchronously detect changes in source code,
  # routes, locales, etc. This feature depends on the listen gem.
  # config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
  #
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: 'localhost', port: 3000}

  Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"

  config.paperclip_defaults = {
      :storage => :s3,
      :s3_credentials => {
          :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
          :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
          :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
      }
  }
end
```

paperclip.rb

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com'
```

pins_controller.rb

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /pins
  # GET /pins.json
  def index
    @pins = Pin.all
  end

  # GET /pins/1
  # GET /pins/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /pins/new
  def new
    @pin = current_user.pins.build
  end

  # GET /pins/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /pins
  # POST /pins.json
  def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @pin.save
        format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @pin }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @pin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /pins/1
  # PATCH/PUT /pins/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @pin.update(pin_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @pin }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @pin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /pins/1
  # DELETE /pins/1.json
  def destroy
    @pin.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to pins_url, notice: 'Pin was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_pin
      @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def pin_params
      params.require(:pin).permit(:description, :image)
    end

  def correct_user
    @pin = current_user.pins.find_by(id: params[:id])
    redirect_to pins_path, notice: "Nie jesteś uprawniony do edycji tego pinu" if @pin.nil?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have made the same mistake I did before. In your development.rb file, do not edit the text to add your specific S3 keys. Just copy-paste the text directly as is listed in the tutorial.

```rb
#development.rb
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

Then, set the environmental variables AWS_BUCKET, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY as described by the author of the dev center article.

Btw, I'm not sure why you are using PaperClip(deprecated gem) on Rails 6. Rails 6 has ActiveStorage library to do the same thing perfectly.